# Google maps geocoding returns empty string

Tags: api, google-maps, geocoding

Yesterday I created a new Google map geocoding API key on the developper console. I need to get gps coordinates from a server script. When I use the "which key do I need" in the console, it tells me I choosed the right key. I also allowed the fixed IP of my server in the key settings.

Now, when I use "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MY_ADDRESS&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY", it returns an empty string.

When I use "http//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MY_ADDRESS&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY" it returns a warning about this kind of queries must use https (which is consistent with the doc).

And finally, when I use "http//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MY_ADDRESS&sensor=false" (no https and no key) I get the relevant data, either in json or xml. As explained in the doc, this can be used with a limit of 2500 geocoding per day, but the problem is that I have different domains on the same server (with the same IP) that geocode, and since google tracks by IP to evaluate daily quotas...

So my question is : what am I missing when trying to geocode an address using https and the key ?
The only thing that crossed my mind is : do I need to activate billing in google maps, even though I know for sure that I will never exceed the free quota of 2500 queries per day, at least with the project to which the key is associated ?

Thanks in advance for any tip or advice.

Comment: How do you use this, are you entering the URL in your browser or are you making a request using some form of script?

Comment: which kind of server-script do you use? Are you sure that  https-requests are supported on your server?

Comment: The "return an empty string" response is not an expected behavior. It seems that the error lies in how you handle the response. If you are using the request directly on your browser it should at least return an [error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes) if it does not return a place.